# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Timedelta' and 'datetime.time - python

Tags: python, pandas, time

My code is the following:

```
 import datetime
 df_time_size=result1.loc[:, ['time']].copy()
 time_interval = datetime.timedelta(minutes=number)
 df_time_size.loc[:, 'time'] = (df_time_size.loc[:, 'time'] + time_interval)
```

My df_time_size is a datetime column with 12:00:00
I want it to store in that column whatever the times are plus the time_interval so if `number=5` the first entry would be 12:05:00 however, I get the following error:
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Timedelta' and 'datetime.time'` for the line: `df_time_size.loc[:, 'time'] = (df_time_size.loc[:, 'time'] + time_interval)`
I tried:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
time_interval = timedelta(minutes = number)
```

Also tried:

```
 df_time_size.loc[:, 'time']=dt.datetime.combine( df_time_size.loc[:, 'time'] + timedelta)
```

but both give me the same exact error.

Edited():
My df_time_size is also a datetime `df_time_size['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_time_size['time'], format='%H:%M:%S').dt.time`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me. Is your `df_time_size['time']` a `datetime` type?

```
time_interval = datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
df_time_size = pd.DataFrame({'time': ['12:00:00']})
df_time_size['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_time_size['time'])
df_time_size.loc[:, 'time'] = (df_time_size.loc[:, 'time'] + time_interval)
print(df_time_size)
```

Output:

```
                 time
0 2020-03-15 12:05:00
```

If I don't convert `df_time_size['time']` to a `datetime` type, it still works.

```
time_interval = datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
df_time_size = pd.DataFrame({'time': ['12:00:00']})
df_time_size.loc[:, 'time'] = (df_time_size.loc[:, 'time'] + time_interval)
print(df_time_size)
```

Output:

```
      time
0 12:05:00
```

Can you post the `df` you are having? It will better explain the problem you are having.

Comment: My df_time_size is in `pd.to_datetime` and i read online that you cannot `+` two datetimes, I think that is why it is not working.

Comment: It worked for me when converting my df_time_size to the format you showed above

Comment: Glad, I was able to help!!